# Cubic Bezier Curves - Calculate Y for any given X

Tags: bezier-curve

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an explicit form for cubic Bézier curves?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/is-there-an-explicit-form-for-cubic-bezier-curves)

I want to calculate Y for any given X of a bezier to help me chart a graph.

X represents time and Y represents distance from an object.

I got this formula for cubic beziers:

$$X(t) = (1-t)^3  X_0 + 3(1-t)^2  t  X_1 + 3(1-t)  t^2  X_2 + t^3  X_3$$

$$Y(t) = (1-t)^3  Y_0 + 3(1-t)^2  t  Y_1 + 3(1-t)  t^2  Y_2 + t^3  Y_3$$

I need to know what $t$ is for $X$ to I can work out what $Y$ would be for $t$... right?

So I need to rearrange this formula with $t$ on the left, I think:

$$X(t) = (1-t)^3  X_0 + 3(1-t)^2  t  X_1 + 3(1-t)  t^2  X_2 + t^3  X_3$$

Ummmm... is this right?

Comment: I think that normally you'd start with t, find x and find y. I am not sure why you are starting with x?

Answer (score 1):

One way to graph $Y$ in terms of $X$ would be to choose { X0, X1, X2, X3 } so that $X( t ) = t$, so you can choose the control points { 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1 }.

Comment: I'm sorry that doesn't make sense to me. Can you possibly link me to a page with more detailed explanation?

Comment: I found this... http://degrafa.googlecode.com/svn/branches/Origin/Degrafa/com/degrafa/geometry/AdvancedQuadraticBezier.as what technique do they use? (see xAtY)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question then. The function xAtY first converts a quadratic bezier to power basis form. The resulting quadratic equation is solved to find the t corresponding to the given Y. The bezier curve is then evaluated at the two roots to get the X.