# Understanding of cubic Bézier curves in one dimension

Tags: parametric, cubics, bezier-curve

I am implementing **cubic Bézier** equation to my project for smooth animation. I'm being stuck at how to calculate **progress** at a **time**. I found an equation in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/348645/514491) and it's really close to what I am finding. Here is the equation:

$$
y = u_0(1-x)^3 + 3u_1(1-x)^2x + 3u_2(1-x)x^2 + u_3x^3
$$
As my understanding, $x$ represent for the **time** and $y$ represent for the **progress**. But what is $u_0, u_1, u_2, u_3$? I know a Bézier curve is defined by a set of 4 points $P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3$. But i can not figure out the relation of 4 points $P$ and 4 constant $u$.
Example in the answer above, an **ease-in** curve has $u_0=0$, $u_1=0.05$, $u_2=0.25$, $u_3=1$ but if we use the point it should be $P_0=(0,0); P_1=(0.42,0); P_2=(1,1); P_3=(1,1); $ (you can see it [here](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.42,0,1,1)).
I want to know how to get the constant $u$ base on the point $P$.
Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!
**Edit:** When i fixed $P_0=(0,0), P_3=(1,1)$ is there any equation that take $P_1, P_2$ as the parameter like the [css cubic-bezier function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function#Timing_functions)?

Comment: I like your love towards cubic-bezier as I love implementing in CSS

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A 2D Bézier curve is controlled by four 2D **control points**, say $\mathbf{P}_0$, $\mathbf{P}_1$, $\mathbf{P}_2$, $\mathbf{P}_3$. Its equation is
$$
\mathbf{P}(t) = (1-t)^3\mathbf{P}_0 +  3t(1-t)^2\mathbf{P}_1 
                + 3t^2(1-t)\mathbf{P}_2 + t^3\mathbf{P}_3
\tag{1}\label{eq1} 
$$
This is a "parametric" equation -- given a parameter value $t$ (which you can regard as time), this formula gives you a 2D point $\mathbf{P}(t)$. Writing $x$ and $y$ coordinates separately, the curve is
$$
x(t) = (1-t)^3 x_0 +  3t(1-t)^2 x_1 + 3t^2(1-t) x_2 + t^3 x_3
\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
$$
y(t) = (1-t)^3 y_0 +  3t(1-t)^2 y_1 + 3t^2(1-t) y_2 + t^3 y_3 
\tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$
where $\mathbf{P}_i = (x_i,y_i)$ for $i=0,1,2,3$. This is the type of Bézier curve found in typical drawing programs or graphics packages. It's good for animating a point moving in 2D, but not very good for controlling movement in 1D.

Another approach would be to use an equation like \eqref{eq1} above to describe $y$ as a function of $x$:
$$
y(x) = (1-x)^3 y_0 +  3x(1-x)^2 y_1 + 3x^2(1-x)y_2 + x^3y_3
\tag{4}\label{eq4}
$$
We might call this a "functional" Bézier curve, as opposed to a parametric one. 
Here, we don't have four control points, we have four **control values**, $y_0$, $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$. The functional form is less general, but it's quite suitable for use in animation: it gives you the "progress" $y(x)$ corresponding to a given time $x$.

So, how are the functional Bézier curve and the parametric one related? The answer is that the functional one is a special case of the parametric one. Suppose we substitute $x_0=0$, $x_1 = \tfrac13$, $x_2 = \tfrac23$, $x_3 = 1$
into equation \eqref{eq2} above. Then we get
$$
x(t) = (1-t)^3 (0) +  3t(1-t)^2 (\tfrac13) + 3t^2(1-t) (\tfrac23) + t^3 (1) = t
$$
So $x=t$, and equation \eqref{eq3} from above becomes
$$
y(t) = y(x) = (1-x)^3 y_0 +  3x(1-x)^2 y_1 + 3x^2(1-x)y_2 + x^3y_3
$$
which is the same as equation \eqref{eq4}.
So, in short, to get a Bézier **function** with control values $y_0$, $y_1$, $y_2$, $y_3$, we just need to construct a 2D Bézier **curve** with control points $\mathbf{P}_0 = (0,y_0)$, $\mathbf{P}_1 = (\tfrac13,y_1)$, $\mathbf{P}_2 = (\tfrac23,y_2)$, $\mathbf{P}_3 = (1,y_3)$.

For example, if you have the control values you mentioned: $u_0=0$, $u_1=0.05$, $u_2=0.25$, $u_3=1$, then the corresponding 2D control points are $(0,0)$, $(\tfrac13, 0.05)$, $(\tfrac23, 0.25)$, $(1,1)$.

[image]

Conversely, suppose you have four control points  $\mathbf{P}_0 = (0,0)$, $\mathbf{P}_1 = (x_1,y_1)$, $\mathbf{P}_2 = (x_2,y_2)$, $\mathbf{P}_3 = (1,1)$ describing a 2D Bézier curve, and you want to find the corresponding Bézier function. In general, this is not possible. In fact, it's only possible if 
$x_1 = \tfrac13$ and $x_2 = \tfrac23$. And, in that case, the Bézier function defined by the control values $0, y_1, y_2, 1$ will give you the desired shape.

This causes lots of problems. Like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127059/finding-y-coordinate-given-x-coordinate-of-cubic-bezier-curve-under-restrict?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/is-there-an-explicit-form-for-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-curves?noredirect=1&lq=1). People design a 2D Bézier **curve**, and then they want to use it as a **function** (i.e. they want to get the $y$ value corresponding to a given $x$). This is generally not possible (or, at least, it's not easy). If you want to control animation in 1D, I think you should use a function, not a 2D Bézier curve.

For example, suppose you try to find a function corresponding to the 2D curve with control points $\mathbf{P}_0 = (0,0)$, $\mathbf{P}_1 = (1,0)$, $\mathbf{P}_2 = (0,1)$, $\mathbf{P}_3 = (1,1)$. This curve looks like this:

[image]

You can't possibly represent this curve as the graph of a polynomial function (of any degree) because it has vertical slope at $x=\tfrac12$, which would never happen with a polynomial. If you want to use this curve for 1D animation, then you need to be able to calculate the $y$ value for a given $x$. In general, you will need to [solve cubic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) to do this, which requires either nasty unstable formulas or numerical methods like Newton-Raphson. This particular example is very special because the relevant cubic is easy to solve, giving us:
$$
y = \frac{1}{48}(36 - 24x) + \frac34 (2x-1)^{1/3}
$$
But this is highly unusual; the solution of a cubic equation is typically a huge mess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me so much. I see in your answer that we need to fix the x-cordinate of 4 points to map it to the **function** but in the http://cubic-bezier.com the $P_0=(0,0), P_3=(1,1)$ and the input is $P_1(x_1, y_1), P_2(x_2, y_2)$. It is same as css cubic-bezier function. Is there any way that we can achieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But I'm guessing that it might be the issue I discuss in the new paragraph at the end of my answer.

Comment: It is what i am asking  about. Css has a [cubic-bezier() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function#Timing_functions) what have $P_0=(0,0), P_1=(x_1, y_1), P_2=(x_2, y_2), P_3=(1,1)$ and some how it can use $P_1$ and $P_2$ as the input to control the animation.

Comment: After all, i can use the function with the control value $(0, y_1, y_2, 1)$ to control animation but it is better if i can make my function like the css way.

Comment: Yes, but there are two different things: the function with control values $0,y_1,y_2,1$, and the 2D Bezier curve with control points $(0,0), (x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (1,1)$. The two graphs won't be the same unless $x_1 = \tfrac13$ and $x_2 = \tfrac23$.

Comment: Thank you so much. At least i have a function to control the animation. I will keep finding the way to implement exactly css cubic-bezier function.

Comment: I would guess that the css implementation uses numerical methods internally to calculate the $y$ corresponding to a given $x$. You could do the same, but it's a bunch of work. Much easier to use a Bezier function instead.

Comment: I hope css does not use that way because css animation is very lightweight.

Comment: After a long bounty period, i did not receive any answer. So i think, your solution is the best and i should follow it. Thank you for your time. You deserve the bounty

Comment: FYI, the CSS implementation in browsers (at least Firefox, anyway) does use numeric methods; more information (and a pure JS implementation) can be found in [this blog post](http://greweb.me/2012/02/bezier-curve-based-easing-functions-from-concept-to-implementation/)

Comment: @DaveJones. Your link is dead. Do you have another one, please.

Comment: @bubba The Wayback machine has you covered: https://web.archive.org/web/20220331085408/http://greweb.me/2012/02/bezier-curve-based-easing-functions-from-concept-to-implementation/ and https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing is a JS implementation linked to from that article

Answer (score 1):

The animation in your second link has only one variable as a function of time. If you want to move a point on the computer screen you'll need to specify two variables, the $x$ and $y$ coordinates, as functions of time. This can be done with a single equation if you write the $(x,y)$ position as a vector. In this case the coefficients $u_i$ in your equation need to be 2-dimensional vectors, and these are identical with the control points $P_i$. This is explained in the  Wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve