# Find value Y on cubic Bézier given value X

Tags: bezier-curve

Okay, I know that this has been asked here a *lot,* but I've read through ~10 other questions exactly like this one, and none of them have provided me with any useful information. In fact, 3 of the answers that I found were straight up inaccurate!

Anyway, my question is very simple (for me it's confusing, but it's probably a walk in the park for you guys), how do I find value Y on a cubic Bézier, given value X?

I have been previously using a `time` property of sorts to iterate over my bezier, but that gives improper results. I found some people suggest that I should be solving for t given X, but I have no idea how I would go about doing that or if that's even the best solution.

Let's say I have the following cubic bezier: `(0,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,1,0)`
If I use `t` to find a point along said bezier, I receive *non-linear results when incrementing `t` linearly.* This is a *huge* problem for me and one that has been stumping me for quite some time.

What I need to do is use X in this case, where I can increase X from 0 to 1 linearly, and use that to sample for a given Y position on my curve, and I believe that this will solve my problem.

Can anybody explain to me how this would be done? Currently the only values that I have to work with are the anchor points + the control points of my bezier, I have no other information about it.

Comment: What does $(0,1,0.5,0.5,1,0)$ mean?

Comment: Those are the coordinates of a linear cubic bezier. They are as follows: `ap1x,ap1y,cp1x,cp1y,cp2x,cp2y,ap2x,ap2y`

Comment: So, why do you have 6 coordinates, not 8?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a typo. I forgot to include the duplicate `0.5,0.5` Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: For your example $X+Y=1$. In general $Y$ will be of degree three over $\mathbb R[X]$.

Comment: I think what you need is covered in the answers to [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571471/understanding-of-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-curves-in-one-dimension)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is covered in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571471/understanding-of-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-curves-in-one-dimension), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127059/finding-y-coordinate-given-x-coordinate-of-cubic-bezier-curve-under-restrict?rq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/is-there-an-explicit-form-for-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-curves?noredirect=1&lq=1).

A 2D Bézier curve is controlled by four 2D **control points**, say $\mathbf{P}_0$, $\mathbf{P}_1$, $\mathbf{P}_2$, $\mathbf{P}_3$. Its equation is
$$
\mathbf{P}(t) = (1-t)^3\mathbf{P}_0 +  3t(1-t)^2\mathbf{P}_1 
                + 3t^2(1-t)\mathbf{P}_2 + t^3\mathbf{P}_3
\tag{1}\label{eq1} 
$$
Writing $x$ and $y$ coordinates separately, the curve is
$$
x(t) = (1-t)^3 x_0 +  3t(1-t)^2 x_1 + 3t^2(1-t) x_2 + t^3 x_3
\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$
$$
y(t) = (1-t)^3 y_0 +  3t(1-t)^2 y_1 + 3t^2(1-t) y_2 + t^3 y_3 
\tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$
where $\mathbf{P}_i = (x_i,y_i)$ for $i=0,1,2,3$.

So, suppose you have a given $x$ value, say $x=k$, and you want to calculate the corresponding $y$ value. The first problem is that there might be more than one corresponding $y$ value, but let’s ignore that issue, for now.

To get the $y$ value, you need two steps:

(A) Find $t$ such that $(1-t)^3 x_0 +  3t(1-t)^2 x_1 + 3t^2(1-t) x_2 + t^3 x_3 =k$.

(B) Substitute this $t$ value into equation (2) to find $y(t)$.

Step (A) is the difficult part, because you will need to [solve a cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) to do this, which requires either nasty unstable formulas or numerical methods like Newton-Raphson.

Comment: Another approach is to determine the degree $3$ polynomial relation between $X$ and $Y$. This is a nasty formula in general, but can be deduced from any $9$ different points on the curve. Once this is done, you easily get a cubic equation in $Y$ for each given $X$. Still requires some numerical approach to solve.

Comment: @WimC. I’d love to know the details. You’re saying that we can express y as a cubic function of x??  And I don’t understand the “9 different points” comment. AFAIK, you can only interpolate 6 points with a parametric cubic curve, and even that is not easy.

Comment: Or do you mean we derive an implicit equation $f(x,y)=0$ by eliminating $t$.

Comment: I guess that implicit equation has 10 coefficients, so we could make it interpolate 9 points.

Comment: Actually, there are very simple ways to get implicit equations of Bézier curves. See chapter 17 of these notes: https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/facpub/1/

Comment: Then, if we fix $x$ in the implicit equation, we have a cubic function of $y$ whose root(s) we can find by formula or numerical methods. I think I get it. Not clear that this approach has any great advantages, though ??

Comment: You get the idea. In the end it still boils down to solving a cubic, so no improvement there.